# How to disable the timeout on the vim leader key?

Tags: vim

When I press <kbd>d</kbd> in vim my statusline says `d` and waits infinitely for further instructions.

When I press my leader (<kbd>,</kbd> for me), it waits for input for a while and then times out.

How can I disable this functionality, and make it wait indefinitely for further instructions?

Comment: `:help 'ttimeout'` can be useful.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: are there any side-effects I must know when clearing timeout? Also the distinction between `timeout` and `ttimeout` is not clear to me, after reading the help page.

Comment: Basically, ESC is a "leader" for arrows and other control sequences, so you might have to press ESC twice instead of once. (There might be some way around it, but I'm too lazy to read further -- that's why I just gave a hint instead of posting an answer)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: well, running `set notimeout` and `set ttimeout` solved my problems, if you add this as answer you'll get a +1 and accepted answer.

Comment: @nightcracker: the other drawback is that it becomes annoying to map `,x` and `,xy` at the same time because Vim won't see the distinction of `,x`+`y` or `,xy`. But I would not recommend using mappings that way anyway. You could also consider just setting a high timeout.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `:help ttimeout`:

```
'timeout', 'to', 'notimeout', 'noto'
boolean (default on)
global
                               
'ttimeout', 'nottimeout'                                               
boolean (default off)
global
{not in Vi}
```

These two options together determine the behavior when
part of a mapped key sequence or keyboard code has
been received:

| timeout | ttimeout | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| off | off | do not time out |
| on | on or off | time out on :mappings and key codes |
| off | on | time out on key codes |

If both options are off, Vim will wait until either the complete
mapping or key sequence has been received, or it is clear that there
is no mapping or key sequence for the received characters.  For
example: if you have mapped "vl" and Vim has received 'v', the next
character is needed to see if the 'v' is followed by an 'l'.
When one of the options is on, Vim will wait for about 1 second for
the next character to arrive.  After that the already received
characters are interpreted as single characters.  The waiting time can
be changed with the 'timeoutlen' option.

On slow terminals or very busy systems timing out may cause
malfunctioning cursor keys.  If both options are off, Vim waits
forever after an entered  if there are key codes that start
with .  You will have to type  twice.  If you do not have
problems with key codes, but would like to have :mapped key
sequences not timing out in 1 second, set the 'ttimeout' option and
reset the 'timeout' option.

NOTE: 'ttimeout' is reset when 'compatible' is set.

From the comments:

> Basically, ESC is a "leader" for arrows and other control sequences, so you might have to press ESC twice instead of once. –  @Anton Kovalenko
>
> Running `set notimeout` and `set ttimeout` solved my problems. – @nightcracker

Comment: May you provide some explanation about why is better to set ttimeout instead of timeout or timeoutlen, please?